# Fortran, static library creating and simplifying (newbie here)

Tags: fortran, static-libraries

I'm somewhat new to Fortran, but I'm starting to collect a lot of functions and subroutines in modules that I use over and over again.  I've been trying to build my own library so that I could call some of these functions and subroutines from new source code that I write.  So far I've been able to get the subroutines to work, but not the functions.  I just don't know how to call the function from with in the code.

Here's an example.  The following function takes in an integer and returns the Identity matrix.

```
module test
contains
function IDENTITY(rows) !RETURNS THE IDENTITY MATRIX                                 
    real, dimension(rows,rows)    :: IDENTITY                                        
    integer, intent(in)           :: rows                                      
    integer                       :: i, j                                                                  
    !f2py intent(in) rows                                                             
    !f2py intent(out) IDENTITY                                                        
    !f2py depend(rows) IDENTITY                                                       
    IDENTITY = ZEROS(rows,rows)                                                      
    do i = 1, rows                                                                   
        do j = 1, rows                                                               
            if (i == j) then                                                         
               IDENTITY(i,j) = 1                                                     
            endif                                                                    
        enddo                                                                        
    enddo                                                                            
end function IDENTITY
end module
```

Now I compile this into an object file then archive it into a library.  I then write a small program in which I'd like to use this function--and here's the problem I want to avoid.  I've figured I have to put a \use\ statement in my source so that it will use the module.  Then I've got to include the path to the .mod when compiling.  But eventually, I'm going to have a whole section full of use statements.  I'd like to avoid having to do all those things and just make everything nice and neat.  Is there a way?  Any help would be great,

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

You can put many subroutines and functions into the contains section of one module.  You don't need a separate module for each.  It makes sense to organize your code by creating modules/files for related procedures (subroutines and functions).

Libraries are a good strategy that I used to use.  In this era 
I usually don't bother with the library.  Compilers are so fast that I just compile the files with the modules needed by the program.  It depends on how big your code is.

You invoke a subroutine with a call statement.  You invoke a function by using it in an expression such as an assigment statement:

```
x = sin (y)
matrix = identity (n)
```

P.S. Instead of:

```
do i = 1, rows
   do j = 1, rows
      if (i == j) then
         IDENTITY(i,j) = 1
      endif
   enddo
enddo
```

why not:

```
do i = 1, rows
   IDENTITY(i,i) = 1
enddo
```

Do you have a function ZEROS to zero your matrix?  The language will do that with an assigment statement:

```
IDENTITY = 0.0
```